# Why is my particle system showing on only half the mesh?

Tags: armature, particles, pose-mode

I have a particle system on several icospheres, all parented to a skeletal mesh. In default pose mode, everything renders just fine. But when I start to move the skeleton a bit, one particular ico sphere will only render with half of the particles. No other ico spheres do this. What went wrong here?

[link to blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h0YqF2kVnhDDBogbOwJBkf6wy0Szndyp/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file because we have no idea how you made it....

Comment: @Chris OK, I attached a link to the file above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your object Icosphere, just move the armature modifier before the particle system:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I feel silly for missing this. Thanks for catching it!